# How to replicated countifs functionality of excel in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a "Monthly orders" column which calculates how many transactions a customer with specific id had within a specific CohortDate.

Basically, it's a COUNTIFS function where RANGES are all IDS and all CohortDates equal to ID and CohortDate of any given row.

Any help is much appreciated.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'order_id': [75054,75057,75059,75061,75066],
                   'customer_id': [101692,101694,101734,101692,101694],
                   'CohortDate': ['2016-05','2016-05','2016-05','2016-05','2016-06'] 
                  })
```

The result I would aim to get is the following:

```
order_id    customer_id    CohortDate    Monthly_orders

75054    101692    '2016-05'    2

75057    101694    '2016-05'    1

75059    101734    '2016-05'    1

75061    101692    '2016-05'    2

75066    101694    '2016-06'    1
```

Comment: Please have a look at [*How to make good reproducible pandas examples*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Then edit the question and provide a sample of your data and the expected output (in text format).

Comment: what's the specific logic?

Comment: In excel the logic for the second row would be as followed =COUNTIFS(C:C;C2;B:B;B2)

Column C is Cohort Date
Column B is CustomerID

Comment: your output doesn't match the logic, row 5 is 2 on my excel, the above would be `df.groupby(['customer_id','CohortDate'])['customer_id'].transform('count')`

Comment: my bad, corrected it. thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to group by certain variables, we can use the `transform` which applies the groupby accross a series rather than returning a new dataframe.

```
df.groupby(['customer_id','CohortDate'])['customer_id'].transform('count')
```

this returns the count across the original data frame.

```
order_id    customer_id CohortDate  count
0   75054   101692  2016-05 2
1   75057   101694  2016-05 1
2   75059   101734  2016-05 1
3   75061   101692  2016-05 2
4   75066   101694  2016-06 1
```

Comment: don't forget to green tick once u can :)